# How to get telegram's channel description in Telethon?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telethon

I'm writing a client of telegram using Telethon. How can i get channel description? `get_entity` method does not provide channel description.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is [GetFullChannelRequest](https://lonamiwebs.github.io/Telethon/methods/channels/get_full_channel.html) method

```
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetFullChannelRequest
# creating client here
ch = client.get_entity("@mychannel")
ch_full = client(GetFullChannelRequest(channel=ch))
ch_full.full_chat.about # this is what you need
```

So you may want to inspect `full_chat` attribute as it includes rest of info

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [getChat](https://tg.sean.taipei/payload.php?getChat-ef20df5f) method with `chat_id` or `@username`, and `.result.description` is what you need.

Comment: Could you add some lines of code. Is `getChat` method of `Channel` class?

Comment: In fact, I didn't know how to use it in Python, it is Bot API method :(

Answer (score 1):

Another example of usage with a bot

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events
from telethon import functions

bot = TelegramClient(
    'bot', API_ID, API_HASH).start(bot_token=BOT_TOKEN)

@bot.on(events.NewMessage)
async def my_event_handler(event):
    chat = await event.get_chat()
    result = await bot(functions.messages.GetFullChatRequest(
        chat_id=chat.id
    ))
    print(result.full_chat.about)

bot.run_until_disconnected()
```